# How to delete Json by a unique ID from php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, json

I'd like to delete a JSON object which pid is 4 from php. the pid is a unique value. How to achieve this?

obdatabase.json

```
{"pobject":[{"pname":"Pikachu","pid":"1"},
{"pname":"squirtle","pid":"2"},
{"pname":"Justinbieber","pid":"3"},
{"pname":"Superman","pid":4}]}
```

delete.php

My attempt so far.

```
<?php

    $file="obdatabase.json";
    $json = json_decode(file_get_contents($file),TRUE);



 foreach ($json->pobjects as $pobject) {
    if ($pobject->pid == 1) {
                    unset($pobject);
                    file_put_contents($file, json_encode($json));
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Check out https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php - It lets you create a function that determines what stays in the array or not based on a boolean it returns.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how it could be done using array-filter, for removing the object with PID 4:

```
<?php

    $file="obdatabase.json";
    $json = json_decode(file_get_contents($file),FALSE);

    function filterPID($var)
    {
        // returns whether the input integer is not 4
        return(!($var->pid == 4));
    }

    $cleaned_array = array_filter($json, "filterPID");

?>
```

Comment: except using `TRUE` in json_decode will make whole structure arrays, not objects

Comment: Good point. I imagine the asker had intended that to be false, since he referenced ->pid in his code. [Edited answer to fix]

Comment: or OP doesn't realize problem. Second argument not needed as `FALSE` is default ..not sure what intent was

Comment: Aware of it being an optional argument, I've left it there for clarity to the OP. Or something like that

Answer (score 0):

alternate solution based on [@Hiphop03199](https://stackoverflow.com/users/770378/hiphop03199):

```
$file="obdatabase.json";
$json = json_decode(file_get_contents($file), TRUE);

function filterPID($var) 
{
    return(!($var['pid'] == 4));
}

$cleaned_array = array_filter($json['pobject'], "filterPID");
```